# Configure bosch cameras through Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 22.04, camera

I am trying to configure Bosch network cameras,my OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. On Windows systems, Bosch provides a software called *Configuration Manager*, through which cameras can be initialized (setting up IPs, passwords etc.) for the very first time. But in case of Ubuntu, there is no such software. So, how can I initialize the cameras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Bosh IP cameras (and you have not given any model details), but with other (e.g. HikVision) IP cameras you can initialise them via the camera built-in web interface.

You enter the IP address of the camera into your browser and then usually the first thing it asks for is for you to set a admin password, you can then access configuration options including a specific/static IP address/subnet etc.

HikVision cameras come set with a default IP address so you need to ensure your PC is on the same network subnet of that address to be able to connect to the web interface.

Your Bosch cameras will either have a default IP address or will use DHCP by default. If DHCP you will need to identify the IP address your network assigns to the camera and then put that IP address into a browser.